# Multi-az deployment in AWS Aurora and read replicas

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, rds

can someone help me with these questions please :

**1-** the documentation stated that Aurora will automatically fail-over to the read replicas, my question is how does it select the replica which will be promoted if you have more than one with different instances class?

**2-** can I disable this automatic fail-over (just asking, not stating that I will do it)

**3-** what is the purpose of multi-az in Aurora if you can have the same effect with much more control on instances classes while creating replicas and let Aurora do the auto fail-over for you. please correct me if I am wrong with this assumption.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm for election of a new master in case of failure is not really documented... but it doesn't seem to matter, because Aurora replicas seem to be different than other RDS replicas, because all the instances in the cluster are necessarily of the same instance class.

Unlike other RDS offerings, read replicas in Aurora do not appear to have an independent copy of the backing store -- instead, the backing store itself provides redundancy, being replicated at the storage level with two copies in each of three availability zones.

> The cluster volume is made up of multiple copies of the data for the DB cluster, but the data in the cluster volume is represented as a single, logical volume to the primary and Aurora Replicas in the DB cluster.
>
> Because the cluster volume is shared among all instances in your DB cluster, no additional work is required to replicate a copy of the data for each Aurora Replica.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Replication.html

Multi-AZ in Aurora is also not the same thing -- with other RDS products, multi-AZ involves a second, invisible instance, running in parallel with the master.  The Aurora literature uses the phrase "multi-AZ technology," but the meaning appears to be different.  Note that the Aurora pricing tables don't show a separate pricing rate for "multi-AZ" the way MySQL and MariaDB do.

Failover doesn't appear to be something that can be disabled.  Even if you have no replicas, Aurora will still "fail over" if the master fails -- but it does it by spinning up a replacement master using the existing cluster volume as the backing store.

Comment: hi, I have just tested the replica creation and AWS allowed me to have multiple instance classes in the same cluster. regrading the multi-AZ and auto fail-over to a replica, I still don't get the deference from the availability standing point.

Comment: One of the questions still remains. Why use Amazon multi AZ deployment of Aurora DB cluster, if Aurora itself is capable of healing itself. If it keeps 2 copies in 3 AZs, then its as reliable as using the multi AZ replica setup for failover. Also, during failover. it automatically creates another instance (if no read replica exist) or switches the primary. 

I really do not understand any need to create additional requirement of using multi AZ aurora cluster. Please comment

Comment: @PPrasad, as I pointed out in the answer, above, Aurora **doesn't have** a Multi-AZ provisioning/pricing option like RDS for MySQL has, for exactly the reason you stated: if a replica is available, it is promoted; if not, one is created.  The master and replicas are what make up a "cluster."

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is no longer valid anymore.

> Multi AZ = Aurora Cluster with at least one Read Replica in a
> different AZ.

You can still create multiple read replicas for a cluster but if you create them within the same AZ of your writer, cluster will not be multi AZ.

> Within each AWS Region, Availability Zones (AZs) represent locations that are distinct from each other to provide isolation in case of outages. We recommend that you distribute the primary instance and reader instances in your DB cluster over multiple Availability Zones to improve the availability of your DB cluster. That way, an issue that affects an entire Availability Zone doesn't cause an outage for your cluster.
>
> You can set up a Multi-AZ cluster by making a simple choice when you create the cluster. The choice is simple whether you use the AWS Management Console, the AWS CLI, or the Amazon RDS API. You can also make an existing Aurora cluster into a Multi-AZ cluster by adding a new reader instance and specifying a different Availability Zone.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.AuroraHighAvailability.html